# Detect Touch event in UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview

I want to finish such a demand, in the interface embedded UIWebView control, when the user clicks on a blank area and the area that link, jump to different new interface, but I can't distinguish between the two. Could someone help me?

I try put an transparent NSView over an UIWebView, and overide the touchesDidBegin etc, then send them to your webview. Ex: But the UIWebView can't accept touch events。